# Profiling issues VisualVM and Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, visualvm

Recently (I suspect the latest Java update installed a few days ago, but I'm not sure), I am experiencing some strange problems with VisualVM run under Mac OS 10.8.4. The profiler has been working fine for ages, but now suddenly, the CPU profiling doesn't show me any methods from my own applications any longer, but only the following four:

```
sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run()
sun.awt.AWTAutoShutdown.run()
sun.awt.AppContext$PostShutdownEventRunnable.run()
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()
```

We tried on a colleague's Mac (similar configuration, latest updates installed), and it's still working fine for him.

Any hints what might be causing that problems are warmly welcome.

[edit] It is a command line program, **no** AWT application.

Comment: And the application is running normally? Since the above looks like AWT has shut down automatically, which could be due to the famous Cocoa issue with `-XstartOnFirstThread`.

Comment: Yes, the application is running just fine. I forgot to mention: It is **no AWT application**, but purely command line based.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason your CPU profiling settings are messed up. Please see [Profiling VisulVM](https://blogs.oracle.com/nbprofiler/entry/profiling_with_visualvm_part_2), especially 'Profiling Performance' section. It will describe the settings.